# Reviewing, Do not close

Tags: discussion, review

So when I review a question for closing, and I click Do not close, does this do anything?  The number of votes to close doesn't change.  Does this take it out of the list of review questions for closing?

For example, I just got [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111925/completing-the-square-for-2x-x2) question and it already has 3 votes to close because it's too localized.  I strongly disagree that it is too localized.  I think maybe people think it's too easy.  Just because it asks how to complete the square for a specific polynomial does not mean it is too localized.  The answer given still gives the general method for completing the square.  This is akin to saying a specific integral problem is too localized, whereas in reality seeing the one integral could give a technique for many others.  So, I clicked Do not close.  But, since I am not sure that does anything, I also posted a comment explaining why.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-new-do-not-close

Comment: @lvk Thanks!   ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LVK provided a [link in his comment above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-new-do-not-close). Here I copy-and-paste the "official" answer to what happens:

> Normally, a question must hit 100 views before close votes age away,
>   so as to give enough folks time to see and review it. Questions with
>   close votes stay in the review queue until they are closed or the
>   votes expire.
>
> But if 5 people select "Do Not Close" within the review queue, the
>   question will be immediately removed from the queue (not shown to any
>   more reviewers) and the aging starts immediately.
>
> This doesn't prevent it from being closed, mind you - if someone
>   visits the question directly and votes to close it, that'll both count
>   toward the 5 votes needed to close it and stall the aging for another
>   four days - but it will both reduce the number of people viewing it
>   and hasten the removal of votes on questions for which there is
>   clearly no support for closing.